# How do i get use one variable as a key and one as a value in a localStorage.setItem in jquery?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm having trouble getting my head around the localStorage thing.

I've set a variable "time" and a variable "text" (time from what row i've entered some data in, and text from the data entered in the text box)

When i try localStorage.setItem(time, text) it saves the result for time as both the key and the value. if i use localStorage.setItem("time", text) it saves the "time" as the key and the result for text as the value.

The result i WANT is the variable for time (the row the text is entered in eg. "8") as the key and the variable for test (whatever is typed in the text field eg "my text here")

Help a noob out!

Thanks!

(here's the chunk of code)

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var rowTd = $(this).parents();
        var text = rowTd.find("textarea").val();
        console.log("textarea", text);
        var directParent = $(this).parent();
        var th = directParent.siblings("th");
        var time = th.attr("id");
        localStorage.setItem(time, text);
```

Comment: Have you checked what the variable time you try to use as a key is? maybe add a console.log to verify that there is actually a value

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response :) this is solved now, after console logging (a lot) and then turning the correct console log into the setItem - thanks heaps!